# Converting a String into a Char for this JOptionPane program

Tags: string, char, joptionpane

I'm attempting to convert my operation variable into a char so that it will work with my if statements.  How would I go about doing this?  The following is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Java_Calculator
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String firstnumber, secondnumber, operation;

        double num1;
        double num2;
        double sum;
        double sub;
        double div;
        double mul;
        double mod;

        firstnumber = 
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the first Operand: ");

        secondnumber =
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the second Operand: ");

        operation =
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the Operator: ");

         num1 = Double.parseDouble (firstnumber);
         num2 = Double.parseDouble (secondnumber);

         sum= num1 + num2;
         sub= num1 - num2;
         div= num1 / num2;
         mul= num1 * num2;
         mod= num1 % num2;

         if (operation == '+'){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, sum);}

         if (operation == '-'){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, sub);
         }

         if (operation == '/'){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, div);
         }

         if (operation == '*'){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, mul);
         }

         if (operation == '%'){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, mod);
         }
    }
}
```

I'm going to just assume that my if statements are correct for now.  Just looking for the best way to convert that operation variable into a char.

Comment: Assuming the input is correct, your operator is the first char: `operation.charAt(0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 String a=JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("Enter the Operator: ");
    char ch=a.charAt(0); //charAt(int index of string)
    if(ch=='+'){
    .......
    }
    .....
    .....
    .....
```

Comment: Please add some explanation on how this solves the issue